# Rack Attack Throttling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rackattack

I am trying to throttle some bots trying to brute force authentication on our production server.

This is a Rails 4 app with rack attack 6.3 and i have configured it like this:

**`config/initializers/rack_attack.rb`**

```
class Rack::Attack

  # Throttle all requests by IP (60rpm)
  #
  # Key: "rack::attack:#{Time.now.to_i/:period}:req/ip:#{req.ip}"
  throttle('req/ip', limit: 300, period: 5.minutes) do |req|
    unless req.path.start_with?('/assets')
      Rails.logger.error("Rack::Attack Too many requests from IP: #{req.ip}")
      req.ip
    end
  end

  ### Prevent Brute-Force Attacks ###

  # Throttle any POST requests by IP address
  #
  # Key: "rack::attack:#{Time.now.to_i/:period}:pink/posts/ip:#{req.ip}"
  throttle('pink/posts/ip', limit: 1, period: 2.seconds) do |req|
    if req.post?
      Rails.logger.error("Rack::Attack Too many POSTS from IP: #{req.ip}")
      req.ip
    end
  end

end
```

and yet i keep getting millions of requests from the same IP, am i missing something?

The [docs](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack#plugging-into-the-application) say that rails apps use it by default so this should be the only configuration necessary to enable throttling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in the end both syntax like what I had and what @wscourge suggested work, the problem is that even though the official docs say that rails apps use it by default, you still need to add the following to `application.rb`, at least in Rails 4:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the [throttling documentation syntax](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack#throttling), the right way to do it is to **execute** the class method in the initializer, and **not to execute it in the class definition**:

**`config/initializers/rack_attack.rb`**

```
# Throttle all requests by IP (60rpm)
#
# Key: "rack::attack:#{Time.now.to_i/:period}:req/ip:#{req.ip}"
Rack::Attack.throttle('req/ip', limit: 300, period: 5.minutes) do |req|
  unless req.path.start_with?('/assets')
    Rails.logger.error("Rack::Attack Too many requests from IP: #{req.ip}")
    req.ip
  end
end

### Prevent Brute-Force Attacks ###

# Throttle any POST requests by IP address
#
# Key: "rack::attack:#{Time.now.to_i/:period}:pink/posts/ip:#{req.ip}"
Rack::Attack.throttle('pink/posts/ip', limit: 1, period: 2.seconds) do |req|
  if req.post?
    Rails.logger.error("Rack::Attack Too many POSTS from IP: #{req.ip}")
    req.ip
  end
end
```